# Symfony2 How to registrate of two or more records at once.

Tags: forms, symfony

Form/Type

```
class DemoType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
    }

    // ...
}
```

Controller

```
$user = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(new DemoType(), $user);

if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bindRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        return // ...
    }
}
```

View

```
<form action="{{ path }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    <div>
        {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
</form>
```

I would like to register plurality at once.
(Finally I would like to add an input field by the view side.(plus button etc. JavaScript))

What should I do to register two or more users at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the collection form type. See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) for a detailed explanation. The plus button and dynamic creation of new subform has to be handled by javascript but it's all explained in the documentation.